# pandas.read_excel() with list of header rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse an Excel file with a table which has two header rows looking like:

```
| Category A | Category B |
|  1   |  2  |  1   |  2  |
```

According to [the manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) I can pass a list of ints to specify rows to use for a multi-index, but when I do:

```
pd.read_excel(path, header = [1,2])
```

I get back an error saying "list indices must be integers, not list". Apparently I'm not allowed to put any list as `header` kwarg, as I get the same error when doing `header = [1]` (as opposed to `header=1`, which works fine).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not have the Pandas 0.17.0 installed (the man page you linked to).

The read_csv function has been changed - Pandas 0.14.0 (for example) didn't allow a list of ints to be passed as a header argument, [see here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, the rows you put into `header` keyword should be 0-indexed, so you probably want `header=[0,1]`?

Second, there was a bug if the multi-index columns contained numeric values, which will be fixed in 0.17.1 (coming soon), or you can build from master - 
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11328